# Filtering Label in SLD based on Elevation

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

How can I filter the label in **SLD**, I want to have a label for all the contour-lines where the elevation is between `200-400`. I tried with this **SLD**, but it doesn't apply anything.

```
<Rule>
  <Name>rule 6</Name>
  <Title>Label (200-400)</Title>

  <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
        <ogc:Function name="IEEERemainder">
            <ogc:Function name="int2ddouble">
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parseDouble">
                <ogc:Literal>50.0</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:LowerBoundary>
            <ogc:Literal>200</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:LowerBoundary>
        <ogc:UpperBoundary>
            <ogc:Literal>400</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:UpperBoundary>
    </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
</ogc:Filter>

  <MaxScaleDenominator>120000</MaxScaleDenominator>
  <TextSymbolizer>
    <Label>
      <ogc:Function name="round">
        <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
      </ogc:Function>
    </Label>
    <Font>
      <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="font-weight">Normal</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
    </Font>
    <LabelPlacement>
      <LinePlacement/>
    </LabelPlacement>
    <Halo>
      <Radius>
        <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
      </Radius>
      <Fill>
        <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.9</CssParameter>        
      </Fill>
    </Halo>
    <Fill>
      <CssParameter name="fill">#ff0000</CssParameter>
    </Fill>
    <Priority>2000</Priority>
    <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
    <VendorOption name="repeat">300</VendorOption>
    <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</VendorOption>
    <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
    <VendorOption name="spaceAround">30</VendorOption>
  </TextSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```

Comment: why are you calculating the remainder of the value?

Comment: @IanTurton, because I don't want to show all the contour-lines between this range, just some of them(each 5 band) regarding to better performance. and also this is also my whole SLD in this question. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261593/using-range-for-the-value-in-contour-line-in-sld

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter is wrong, currently, it compares the remainder of `(value/50)` to 200 and 400. So if you have contours between 10000 and 20000 they will be drawn and labelled.

I think you want something like:

```
<Rule>
  <Name>Draw Contours</Name>
  <Title>Height (200-400)</Title>

  <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
       <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>      
       <ogc:LowerBoundary>
            <ogc:Literal>200</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:LowerBoundary>
        <ogc:UpperBoundary>
            <ogc:Literal>400</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:UpperBoundary>
    </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
  </ogc:Filter>
  <LineSymbolizer>
    [....]
  </LineSymbolizer>
</Rule>
<Rule>
<ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:And>
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:Function name="IEEERemainder">
        <ogc:Function name="int2ddouble">
            <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="parseDouble">
            <ogc:Literal>50.0</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
    </ogc:Function>
    <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
       <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>      
       <ogc:LowerBoundary>
            <ogc:Literal>200</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:LowerBoundary>
        <ogc:UpperBoundary>
            <ogc:Literal>400</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:UpperBoundary>
    </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
    </ogc:And>
  </ogc:Filter>
  <MaxScaleDenominator>120000</MaxScaleDenominator>
  <TextSymbolizer>
    <Label>
      <ogc:Function name="round">
        <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
      </ogc:Function>
    </Label>
    <Font>
      <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="font-weight">Normal</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
    </Font>
    <LabelPlacement>
      <LinePlacement/>
    </LabelPlacement>
    <Halo>
      <Radius>
        <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
      </Radius>
      <Fill>
        <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.9</CssParameter>        
      </Fill>
    </Halo>
    <Fill>
      <CssParameter name="fill">#ff0000</CssParameter>
    </Fill>
    <Priority>2000</Priority>
    <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
    <VendorOption name="repeat">300</VendorOption>
    <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</VendorOption>
    <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
    <VendorOption name="spaceAround">30</VendorOption>
  </TextSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```